# How to redefine a variable character for the first time in arduino

Tags: char, passwords, arduino-uno

i have this code to Comparison two char

```
    char pass[]="1";
    char passin[100]="";
```

and code to put characters in variable

```
void loop() {

            char key= keypad.waitForKey();  // read char from keypad
            strcat(passin,key);
                  if(strcmp(pass,passin)==0)
                    {  lcd.clear();
                        lcd.print("login success");
                       }else
                    {  lcd.clear();
                     lcd.print("login failed");
                     lcd.setCursor(0,1);
                 }
                  }
delay (1000);
```

}

what the way to return the value of passin as define like first time

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare one character with another you can use the "==" operator. Note that to declare a character you use single quotes e.g. 'a'.

The code can be like this:

```
char pass = '1';
char key;

void loop(){
    key = keypad.waitForKey();  // read char from keypad
    if(pass == key){
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("login success");
    }else {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.print("login failed");
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

The character key will be set to the new value every iteration of the loop.